# Where is the most stable orbit in the Earth/Moon system?

Tags: orbital-motion, stability

Cis Lunar orbit, trans Lunar orbit, lunar orbit, Earth/Moon L4/5? What altitude, eccentricity/inclination? Moon resonance? Stable means not crash into Earth/Moon or escape.

It's a chaotic n>2 body problem. The Sun and other planets may perturb L4/5 "orbits".

The idea is to capture a tiny black hole with significant Hawking radiation (e.g. 1.887e13 kg, 1 MW) and park it in a place where it won't get lost. Or put a data crystal there. Atmospheric drag, solar wind and light pressure may be negligible for the BH, but relevant for the data crystal.

Stability for 4 Ga is sufficient, as the Sun turns into a red giant eventually.

similar: [Could a black hole maintain a stable orbit around the Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252251/could-a-black-hole-maintain-a-stable-orbit-around-the-earth)

Comment: You should check [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point).

Comment: That's what I meant with "Earth/Moon L4/5".

Comment: [Is Apollo 11's Lunar Module Still In Orbit Around The Moon 52 Years Later?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dBHbLV7xEhc)

Comment: Orbits of the planets are not stable on a scale of gigayears - [Why the Earth exists because of Saturn | Migration of Planets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPouwOKMS2s)

Comment: @mmesser314, Ok, then the most stable orbit will last shorter. How long?